# WIX util:xmlfile File name is Source attribute

Tags: xml, wix

I am moving from a Wise Installer to WIX and am using the util:xmlfile to update a configuration xml file.

This works.

```
<Component Id="config" Guid="*">
  <File Id="config" Source="..\Source\Desktop\prodconfig.xml" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" />
    <util:XmlFile 
      Id="_PORT_" File="[INSTALLDIR]prodconfig.xml"  
      Action="setValue" 
      Name="Port" Value="[PORT]" 
      ElementPath="//Configuration/CommConnectionPools/CommConnectionPool" 
      Sequence='1' />
  </File>
</Component>
```

This does not work.

```
<Component Id="config" Guid="*">
  <File Id="config" Source="..\Source\Desktop\prod-config.xml" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" />
    <util:XmlFile 
      Id="_PORT_" File="[INSTALLDIR]prod-config.xml"  
      Action="setValue" 
      Name="Port" Value="[PORT]" 
      ElementPath="//Configuration/CommConnectionPools/CommConnectionPool" 
      Sequence='1' />
  </File>
</Component>
```

When the .msi executes with the first component, everything is fine.  In the second version, an error is returned "Error 25531. Failed to open XML file..."

As far as I can tell the only difference is the hyphen in the file name.

Any suggestions as to what the difference might be?

Comment: http://community.sharpdevelop.net/forums/t/4316.aspx
something related

Comment: I did not try out your specific scenario but looks like it could be a bug within the WIX source code.

Comment: are you installing on a network or local drive?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try using the file's id instead of hard-coding the name

```
[#config] //which will refer to the File Id
```

instead of

```
[INSTALLDIR]prod-config.xml
```

Comment: That did it!  I know comments that say "Thanks" aren't supposed to be written, but I would not have thought of that as being the difference so... thanks a million.  It makes sense since hyphens aren't permitted in IDs.

Comment: Chris, in your answer you state alternately that the File attribute should use the Component's Id and the File's Id. The Component's Id didn't but the File's Id does.

Answer (score 0):

The value for the `File` attribute for `util:XmlFile` tag should refer to the `Id` attribute for the `File` tag.

In your case this would be

```
<Component Id="config" Guid="*">
  <File Id="config" Source="..\Source\Desktop\prod-config.xml" KeyPath="yes" Vital="yes" />
    <util:XmlFile 
      Id="_PORT_" File="[#config]"  
      Action="setValue" 
      Name="Port" Value="[PORT]" 
      ElementPath="//Configuration/CommConnectionPools/CommConnectionPool" 
      Sequence='1' />
  </File>
</Component>
```

In your example since you use the same identifier for both the `Component` tag and the `File` tag it doesn't matter. But in general you need to use the Id for the `File` tag.

To clarify, if your example used `configComponent` and `configFile` respectively for `Component` and `File` identifiers. It would look like the following:

```
<Component Id="configComponent" Guid="*">
  <File Id="configFile" Source="..\Source\Desktop\prod-config.xml" />
    <util:XmlFile 
      Id="_PORT_" File="[#configFile]"  
[snip]
     />
  </File>
</Component>
```