# WIX execute custom action with admin privilege

Tags: c#, wix, admin, wix3

I have written a custom action for my WIX installer. The action´s Execute-attribute is set to deferred and Impersonate and running before InstallFinalize but it encounters a problem within this action which is the missing admin rigth. The action creates a file in the INSTALLFOLDER which is Program File (x86)

Thats my WIX code:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" 
           Name="WixTesterSetup" 
           Language="1033" 
           Version="1.0.0.0" 
           Manufacturer="WixTester" 
           UpgradeCode="77b7ed9a-5394-43e9-aecb-cd9985368ef6">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="Core" Title="Core" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />

    <UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
      <Publish  Dialog="ExitDialog"
                Control="Finish"
                Event="DoAction"
                Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch Wix Tester" />
    <Property Id="WixShellEecxTarget" Value="[#WixTester.exe]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />

    <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.RegistrationInfoCustomAction.TargetDir)$(var.RegistrationInfoCustomAction.TargetName).CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="RegistrationInfoCustomAction" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="SaveUserInfo" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action='RegistrationInfoCustomAction' Before='InstallFinalize'>NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixTesterSetup">
          <Component Feature="Core">
            <File Id="WixTester.exe" Source="$(var.WixTester.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

  </Product>

</Wix>
```

Simple custom action:

```
    public class CustomActions
{
    [CustomAction]
    public static ActionResult SaveUserInfo(Session session)
    {
        File.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine(session.GetTargetPath("INSTALLFOLDER"), "test.xml"));

        return ActionResult.Success;
    }
}
```

Not intresting WixTester:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Test Started");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Diagnose***: I suspect there is something else wrong than just permissions. Please try the following:

[***Verbose Log File***](http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm): Please create a verbose log file:

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\file.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
```

> ***Hot Log Interpretation Tip***: Search for [**"value 3"**](http://robmensching.com/blog/posts/2010/8/2/the-first-thing-i-do-with-an-msi-log/) in the log file to find errors as explained by [`Rob Mensching`](https://twitter.com/robmen) (Wix & Orca
>   author). MSI log files can be overwhelming otherwise.
>
> More: [How to interpret an MSI Log File](http://blogs.technet.com/b/richard_macdonald/archive/2007/04/02/how-to-interpret-windows-installer-logs.aspx) (and in [PDF format from WayBack](https://web.archive.org/web/20080916030949/http://www.rmacdonald.members.winisp.net/Blog_Docs/Annotated_Windows_Installer_Log.pdf)).

***Debugging Custom Actions***: Are you attaching the debugger to the custom action in question? Please find information here: [WIxsharp debug custom action in console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52878332/wixsharp-debug-custom-action-in-console/52880033#52880033) - and [a direct link to an Advanced Installer demonstration video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ayeBB97_NwA). And a link to [MSDN / Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/nb-no/windows/win32/msi/debugging-custom-actions?redirectedfrom=MSDN).

> ***Debugging In Short***: show a message box and attach to it.

---

***XML Files***: XML files can be installed with [WiX XML features](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49162863/129130) and should not be generated via custom actions. You could also create the file from the application itself on launch in a location writable for the user. Here are a couple of links for the latter:

- ***How to deploy settings files***: [Create folder and file on Current user profile, from Admin Profile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48189243/create-folder-and-file-on-current-user-profile-from-admin-profile/48196886#48196886)
- ***Handling write permission denied***: [System.UnauthorizedAccessException while running .exe under program files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50587622/system-unauthorizedaccessexception-while-running-exe-under-program-files/50588465#50588465)

> ***Recommendation***: I do not know which approach can work for you. Recommend you generate the file via the application and save in the
>   userprofile. One xml file per user.

---

***Links***:

- ***More on logging***: [Enable installation logs for MSI installer without any command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I attach to msiexec.exe process I don´t reach my custom action.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem was that deferred custom actions don´t have access to `session["PropertyName"]` the solution was to use `session.CustomActionData["PORTProperty"]` and pass the variables throught a custom action type 51. The new WIX code looks like:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
    <Product Id="*" 
           Name="WixTesterSetup" 
           Language="1033" 
           Version="1.0.0.0" 
           Manufacturer="WixTester" 
           UpgradeCode="77b7ed9a-5394-43e9-aecb-cd9985368ef6">
        <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />

        <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
        <MediaTemplate />

    <Feature Id="Core" Title="Core" Level="1" ConfigurableDirectory="INSTALLFOLDER" />

    <UI>
      <UIRef Id="WixUI_Minimal" />
      <Publish  Dialog="ExitDialog"
                Control="Finish"
                Event="DoAction"
                Value="LaunchApplication">WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOX = 1 and NOT Installed</Publish>
    </UI>

    <Property Id="WIXUI_EXITDIALOGOPTIONALCHECKBOXTEXT" Value="Launch Wix Tester" />
    <Property Id="WixShellEecxTarget" Value="[#WixTester.exe]" />
    <CustomAction Id="LaunchApplication" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="WixShellExec" Impersonate="yes" />

    <Binary Id="CustomActionBinary" SourceFile="$(var.RegistrationInfoCustomAction.TargetDir)$(var.RegistrationInfoCustomAction.TargetName).CA.dll"/>
    <CustomAction Id="RegistrationInfoCustomAction" BinaryKey="CustomActionBinary" DllEntry="SaveUserInfo" Execute="deferred" Impersonate="no" />
    <CustomAction Id="CustomAction51" Property="RegistrationInfoCustomAction" Value="INSTALLFOLDER=[INSTALLFOLDER]" />

    <InstallExecuteSequence>
      <Custom Action="CustomAction51" Before='InstallFinalize' />
      <Custom Action='RegistrationInfoCustomAction' After='CustomAction51'>NOT Installed</Custom>
    </InstallExecuteSequence>

    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
            <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="WixTesterSetup">
          <Component Feature="Core">
            <File Id="WixTester.exe" Source="$(var.WixTester.TargetPath)" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes"/>
          </Component>
        </Directory>
            </Directory>
        </Directory>

  </Product>

</Wix>
```

The Custom Action now looks like:

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mime;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;

namespace RegistrationInfoCustomAction
{
    public class CustomActions
    {
        [CustomAction]
        public static ActionResult SaveUserInfo(Session session)
        {
            File.Create(System.IO.Path.Combine(session.CustomActionData["INSTALLFOLDER"], "test.xml"));

            return ActionResult.Success;
        }
    }
}
```