# InstallShield installer starts in Resume mode - how can I disable this?

Tags: windows-installer, installshield

I have an installer that I've built and when I double-click setup.exe the first screen I see is the Resuming installation screen. So what would cause an installer to begin in Resume mode? There is a prior installed version (same Upgrade Code - different Product Code) but that installation finished correctly.

Answer (score 1):

> ***Quick Guess***: Please try to check first if you need a **reboot** to complete the installation that is suspended but appears complete?

---

***Reboot & FixIt***: Are you sure the previous installation completed correctly? Maybe there is a reboot pending? Try to reboot? Then maybe try to run this tool: [Microsoft FixIt](http://support.microsoft.com/mats/Program_Install_and_Uninstall) to resolve stuck or suspended installations.

***Suspended***: Suspended Windows Installer (MSI) installations are not very well documented I think, here are some relevant properties and actions and associated documentation:

- `RESUME Property`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/resume
- `AFTERREBOOT Property`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/msi/afterreboot
- `ForceReboot Action`: [Reboot on install, Don't reboot on uninstall](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48840273/reboot-on-install-dont-reboot-on-uninstall)

---

***Links***:

- [Recent answer on logging and debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58863498/129130) (try to check the logging perhaps?)
- [Comprehensive answer on MSI logging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890)