# please wait while windows configures microsoft visual studio 2015 then error 2330

Tags: c#, installation

when i try to rebuild My Project Setup installer

in the first it try to configure as in [This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vAgiB.png)
then this message in [This Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J0Mgh.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ***Express***: **`1)`** `Reboot`, **`2)`** `disable anti-virus`, **`3)`** `launch as admin` and check. Then, if need be: **`4)`** `verbose log`, **`5)`** `event logs`. **`6)`** `Try on a virtual if you still can't get it working? Or secondary computer?` Also **`7)`** `google exact error messages` and check user comments. **`8)`** `Run general Visual Studio update?`

---

> ***Malware?***: Run a full check for malware too? It is all over the place these days.

---

> ***Locks?***: A quick search seems to indicate a permission or patching issue of some sort.
>
> - You can try to **`run the tool with elevated rights`**?
> - You could have disk corruption - **`disk errors`**? `Faulty ACL permissions`? (possible)
> - It also just might be that your **`anti-virus suite`** has locked some file that MSI is trying to put back in place. You can try to
>     disable it temporarily to see. Note that the file can have been
>     quarantined as well (moved somewhere else).

---

> ***Tip***: Maybe check section: ["A Deployment Mnemonic" here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) (down the page, yellow section).

---

***Additionally***: [Please try the few hints here first](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49987350/129130). In essence: **`Reboot`**, get a **`verbose log`** file created, **`check event logs`** and try to **`log in as another user`** (generally only effective for user profile corruption issues, but can help):

Create verbose MSI log:

```
msiexec.exe /I "C:\file.msi" /QN /L*V "C:\msilog.log"
```

- Stefan Kruger's site: http://www.installsite.org/pages/en/msifaq/a/1022.htm - you can enable the logging policy for all MSI operations to log all MSI operations. Section: "*Globally for all setups on a machine*".
- [Logging interpretation tips here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58863498/129130). How to make sense of the MSI log files.

---

***Links***:

- ***MSI Logging, comprehensive***: [Enable installation logs for MSI installer without any command line arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54453922/enable-installation-logs-for-msi-installer-without-any-command-line-arguments/54458890#54458890)

Comment: Just had the same problem and found the culprit to be Kaspersky virus protection, disabling during build resolved the problem, in fact the MSI installer doesn't even launch

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the same error but you can give it a try. Just follow the steps from "How to work around this issue" section of [Trouble installing other products after Visual Studio](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/setup/trouble-installing-other-products-after-visual-studio/) blogpost.

If there are indeed Visual Studio missing folders try to recreate them and see if this helps.

The behavior could just be a self-repair mechanism of the MSI installer of some Visual Studio setup modules triggered by the fact the related Visual Studio installer modules were incorrectly built by MSFT team (the MSI components were simply wrongly defined or sth like that).