# SFXCA: Failed to create new CA process via RUNDLL32. Error code: 5

Tags: c#, windows-installer, installation

I'm getting below error on windows 10 machine after taking windows update version 1909.

MSI (c) (4C:DC) [12:25:25:765]: Connected to service for CA interface.
**SFXCA: Failed to create new CA process via RUNDLL32. Error code: 5**
CustomAction FindOfficeComponents returned actual error code 1603 but will be translated to success due to continue marking
Action ended 12:25:26: FindOfficeComponents. Return value 1.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Google Check***: [Chris Painter's blog](http://blog.iswix.com/2015/08/dtf-bug-with-new-windows-10-apps-and.html). Culprit: DTF custom actions.
>
> "*`It seems this kind of error is triggered by DTF custom actions executed as immediate when the setup is launched from "Apps and Features" manager`*".

---

***Solution***: Are you uninstalling or installing? If you are uninstalling, try the old **`ARP applet`** (**`Add / Remove Programs`**).
 Hold <kbd>Windows Key</kbd> => Tap <kbd>R</kbd> => Type: **appwiz.cpl** => Press: <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in order to open the `Add / Remove Programs Applet`.

---

***Deployment Tools Foundation***: **`DTF`** **`=>`** **`Deployment Tools Foundation`** - included with the [WiX toolset](https://wixtoolset.org/). A .NET wrapper for the Win32 MSI API with value added features: [sample 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52254206/uninstalling-program/52280957#52280957), [sample 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/298841/how-to-programmatically-read-the-properties-inside-an-msi-file/1061606#1061606) (`using Microsoft.Deployment.WindowsInstaller;`).

Makes custom actions possible with emulated code (.NET). Richer API, but more dependencies (.NET Framework) and layers to depend upon - some problems invariably result.

---

> ***Quick Checks***:
>
> - [Google exact error message](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/forums/viewtopic.php?t=34780)
> - Try to reboot and then try again (sorts pending reboots & locks).
> - Temporarily disable anti-virus / security software before deployment (locking & blocking).
> - Make sure you run with admin rights (permissions).

---

***General Purpose Deployment Debugging***:

- [***`Deployment Problems`***: **`Quick check list`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58925349/please-wait-while-windows-configures-microsoft-visual-studio-2015-then-error-233/58926062#58926062)
- [***`Deployment Problems`***: **`Basic check list`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49983606/visual-studio-installer-fails-on-aspnetdiagnosticpack-msi/49987350#49987350)

And more in the the ["Deployment mnemonic" section here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864) and down the page.