# How to create msi installer with wix?

Tags: wix

I want to create an msi installation file using wix.

[I want to create these distributions as wix installation files.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vhTiR.jpg)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Wix xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi">
  <Product Id="*" Name="SetupProject1" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="winitech"     UpgradeCode="5a410445-8d05-44f3-aa33-3662cf67060a">
    <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" InstallScope="perMachine" />
    <MajorUpgrade DowngradeErrorMessage="A newer version of [ProductName] is already installed." />
    <MediaTemplate />
    <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="SetupProject1" Level="1">
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="ProductComponents" />
    </Feature>
  </Product>
  <Fragment>
    <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
      <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
        <Directory Id="INSTALLFOLDER" Name="SetupProject1" />
      </Directory>
    </Directory>
  </Fragment>
  <Fragment>
    <ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER">
      <!-- TODO: Remove the comments around this Component element and the ComponentRef below in order to add resources to this installer. -->
      <!-- <Component Id="ProductComponent"> -->
      <!-- TODO: Insert files, registry keys, and other resources here. -->
      <!-- </Component> -->
    </ComponentGroup>
  </Fragment>
</Wix>
```

There is also a file in a subfolder named symbols.

I think I need to add it to the componentGroup but I don't know how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***Quick "Tutorials"***: A few pointers to samples of WiX in use:

- [WiX Quick-start link collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25004226/msi-vs-nuget-packages-which-are-is-better-for-continuous-delivery/25005864#25005864)
- [WiX demo with Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47972615/129130)
- https://www.firegiant.com/wix/tutorial/ (Firegiant is WiX's commercial branch)
- A couple of samples here: https://github.com/glytzhkof/all - maybe try "***VBScriptWriteToLog***"

***Some observations***: Don't include all build files:

- Don't include the [**`.pdb`** files](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_database) or other files that are meant for debugging ([Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3899586/129130)).
- Don't distribute a debug build, build in release mode and use those files (unless you want to test a debug build internally).
- XML files should generally be installed with [XmlFile and XmlConfig elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49162863/129130).