# WiX installer: can we add a new element in web.config using a patch when it is set to NeverOverwrite=yes in its initial msi

Tags: wix, web-config

I am working on a web application. the Web.config file is set to NeverOverwrite (=yes) in its initial installation. Now i need to add DBproviderfactories like below. Can i add this entire block using XmlFile in a patch.msp? I do not want to write a custom action. All I need is to add this block in the web.config. Any suggestion here is appreciated.

```
<system.data>
<DbProviderFactories>
  <!-- Remove in case this is already defined in machine.config -->      
  <remove invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" />
  <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.122.19.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342" />
</DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: I haven't tried, [maybe check this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49162863/129130).

Comment: Is the Web.config file set to "permanent" in the first version? If not, you will potentially get issues with the file being uninstalled and reinstall during major upgrade scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

> ***Sample***: Maybe try this:
> https://github.com/glytzhkof/WiXUpdateXmlFile

- Below is the gist of it - please use the sample above for testing. The markup below is just for illustration.
- Set the XML file both **permanent** and **never overwrite**.
- See inline instructions in the sample above for testing.
- Check what happens on uninstall - this markup will remove the entries it added.

  ```
      <!-- Set app.config permanent and never overwrite to yes -->
      <Component Feature="ProductFeature" NeverOverwrite="yes" Permanent="yes">
        <File Source="app.config" />
      </Component>

      <!-- The XML update -->

      <!-- Use a NEW GUID here, do not go live with this one -->
      <Component Id="XmlFileUpdate" Guid="{00000000-0000-0000-0000-7405EED51B57}" Feature='ProductFeature'>

        <!--Create New Element-->
        <util:XmlFile Id='XmlSettings1' File='[INSTALLFOLDER]app.config' Action='createElement' Name='MyConfig' ElementPath='//configuration' Sequence='1' />

        <!--Set New Value-->
        <util:XmlFile Id='XmlSettings2' File='[INSTALLFOLDER]app.config' Action='setValue' Name='newVersion' Value='6.6.8' ElementPath='//configuration/MyConfig' Sequence='2' />

        <!--Set New Value-->
        <util:XmlFile Id='XmlSettings3' File='[INSTALLFOLDER]app.config' Action='setValue' Name='Server' Value='Pusevov' ElementPath='//configuration/MyConfig' Sequence='3' />

        <!--Update Existing Value, Existing Element-->
        <util:XmlFile Id='XmlSettings4' File='[INSTALLFOLDER]app.config'
          Action='setValue' Name='newVersion' Value='7.7.7' ElementPath='//configuration/ExistingConfig/bindingRedirect' Sequence='4' />

        <CreateFolder />
      </Component>

    </Directory>
  </Directory>
  ```

---

***Link***:

- [Added new application setting to app.config but MSI won't install it (doesn't overwrite)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49160583/added-new-application-setting-to-app-config-but-msi-wont-install-it-doesnt-ov/49162863#49162863)